# C# XAML Hover Area with Mouse Position

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, hover

i need to implement hover areas to my [Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg1FV.png).
When i enter the last ~ 25% of the Window my Item should appear. 
I tried to make an invisible Grid but an invisible object cant trigger events.
Is it possible to make a hover area with the Mouse Position?

```
   private void BlackMetalClockRing_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        gridExpandInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }

    private void BlackMetalClockRing_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridInformationPanel.Visibility != Visibility.Visible)
        gridExpandInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: Use a transparent area instead of an invisible one. Set `Background="Transparent"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associate the MouseEnter event to a new Border that'll cover your grid, with Background="Transparent". Set `yourBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` at the end of this event (in order to make sure it wont intercept further mouse events).

In the MouseLeave event (which stays associated to your grid), set back `yourBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible`.

Comment: Worked fine, Thank You :)